# XML Document Parsing C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a REST web service that creates a `XMLDocument` I am a bit confused on how access the inner text in `FormattedPrice` using `XMLNode`. I can grad offers but that will give me all the inner text.

```
<Offers>
    <Offer>
       <OfferListing>
          <Price>
            <Amount>1067</Amount>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            <FormattedPrice>$10.67</FormattedPrice>
          </Price>
       </OfferListing>
    </Offer>
</Offers>
```

Comment: Does it have to be an XmlDocument (and not an XDocument) ?

Comment: @Henk I am using an third party library that uses XmlDocument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick [walk-through of XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) will help immensely if you're using the Xml DOM.

This should meet your immediate need:

```
XmlNode n = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Offer/OfferListing/Price/FormattedPrice");
```

That will get you the first Offer's Formatted price (and assumes that your Offers node is the root). Other mechanisms exist in XPath that are a bit less brittle and that's where a tutorial would help you.

Comment: should probably give the complete path, just so a maintainer knows what it going on:  "//Offers/Offer[0]/Price/FormattedPrice"

Answer (score 4):

You are probably be best off using XPath.

```
XmlDocument doc = ...;

XmlNode fPrice;
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
fPrice= root.SelectSingleNode("/Price/FormattedPrice");

return fPrice.InnerText;
```

Here's a good example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/myXPath.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use XElement to parse it:

```
string tmp = @"
<Offers>

<Offer>
 <Price>
   <Amount>1067</Amount>
   <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
   <FormattedPrice>$10.67</FormattedPrice>
 </Price>
 </Offer>
</Offers>";

XElement xml = XElement.Parse(tmp);
string formatedPrice = (string)xml.XPathSelectElement("/Offer/Price/FormattedPrice");
```

Comment: The OP is using XMLDocument/XMLNode, not XDocument/XElement :)

Comment: @Rob: You could convert though.

Answer (score 0):

This should grab the $ amount:

```
var price = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"//Offer/Price/FormattedPrice");
string priceText = price.InnerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

Load what you want into a [XmlNodeList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodelist.aspx) and then pull one explicitly or loop through them...

```
XmlNodeList pricesList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("FormattedPrice");
string firstPrice = pricesList[0].InnerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, your XML is invalid....you are missing the starting OfferListing tag.

Here is yet another option to grab the node text.

```
var xmlString = "<Offers><Offer><OfferListing><Price><Amount>1067</Amount<CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode><FormattedPrice>$10.67</FormattedPrice></Price></OfferListing></Offer></Offers>";

var xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml(xmlString);
var formattedPrice = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("FormattedPrice")[0].InnerText;
```